# How to/Can we apply a "limit" when we use replication in Cloudant?

Tags: couchdb, database-replication, cloudant

I'm replicating a database called "foo" to a database called "bar". There are 10 documents in foo. 5 of the docs have a field called "flag" set to "true".
I'm using a filter for the replication which returns true if the "flag" is "true".

Now, just as I'm setting the "filter" parameter for the replication,  I want to set a "limit" parameter as well so only 2 documents are replicated.
I know that we can set "limit" parameters for other endpoints like "_all_docs", "_changes" and others but it doesn't seem to be working with replication. There's nothing in the cloudant documentation on replication about setting limits as well.

Can we even set a "limit" parameter to replication? If so how do I do that?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing. I want live replication but only for a limited amount of documents (so i have eg. always the 100 most recent documents), to reduce load. My documents are chronologically ordered.

For me it's not important to get exactly 100, but to have an overall limit. Therefore I am thinking about first fetching the 100th doc manually before replication; then usings it's timestamp to filter only for newer documents. The local DB will of course grow bigger than 100, but atleast it's not 1 Mio or so. ;)

Have you found a solution for your case?

Comment: Well, first of all, like I found out and like @GlynnBird says, we can't apply a limit to replication. As I read and experimented with replication more, the less interesting it got. It is a good feature, but certainly has a lot of limitations. One that stood out was that a lot of times, the time taken for replication was long. And also, if you ask me, if you are not using replication in a continuous mode, there is really no real advantage in using replication one way. This is just my personal opinion of course, based on my experiences for my use-case. I might be wrong of course.

Comment: So what I did was use replication for push, and use Search Indexes for pull. I feel Search Indexes are absolutely brilliant. They provide great flexibility in indexing only the fields we are interested in. And there is also of course limit and bookmark features that you can use for pagination.
So for your problem you can give search indexes a try. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you can filter documents when replicating to select documents that have a certain feature (e.g only replicate documents where x >1, or only replicate documents that are not deleted).

But you cannot limit a replication job to a number of documents; it will continue until completion, or in the case of continuous replication it will continue to replicate new/updated/deleted documents in "foo" to "bar" as the data changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's the conclusion I came to as well after going through all the documentation. Thanks for the confirmation. Cheers!